# Concrete color -- dark blotches

Tags: concrete

We're building a house that has poured-in-place concrete walls. I like the look of concrete, and we were planning on leaving some areas naked, both inside and outside the house, with some added stain in some places.

But I just saw the walls for the first time (a couple of weeks after the forms were removed), and they have some very dark ugly blotches on them. Here's a picture, showing a purple stained area (below) and a naked area (above).

[image]

I was expecting some color variation, but not this. The dark areas are almost black, or even a dark green color in some places.

**Questions:**
(1) Are these dark areas likely to fade as the concrete dries?
(2) If they don't, is there some way to treat them (short of using an opaque paint or covering/coating of some sort)

One ray of hope ... I saw a wall immediately after the forms were removed, and it was almost entirely black, but it was lighter when we came back the following day.

Comment: If it's only been a couple weeks you'll have to wait longer.  Concrete hardens quickly but continues to cure for a long time.  The majority of the curing reaction is complete in 30 days, but the process continues for a year or more.

Comment: So, color changes should be expected during "curing" ??